# How do I animate the height of divs, bottom to top, in this scenario?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-float, css-position

I want to create an animated graph of skills.

You can check out an example here : http://jsfiddle.net/aoxyLtLe/9/

The above example is using 3 skills but actually I will be using 11 skills

In order to spread them (`#skills>div:nth-child(1) div` & `#skills>div:nth-child(2) span`) out evenly I'm using floats. Positioning each of these elements absolutely and then trying to spread them out evenly would obviously take ages.

I want the height of `#skills>div:nth-child(1) div` to animate bottom to top.

This is currently not the case as I'm using floats and they can't be placed relative to the bottom in order to achieve a bottom-to-top animation.

CSS :

```
#skills {
    position: absolute;
    width: 410px;
    height: 455px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 10px;   
}

#skills>div:nth-child(1) {
    float: left;
    height: 400px;
    display: table;
    width: auto;
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin-left: 31px;
    margin-top: 44px;
}

#skills>div:nth-child(1) div {
    position: relative;
    width: 77px;
    height: 0;
    background-color: #0597BE;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 12px;
}
#skills>div:nth-child(2) {
    float: left;
    display: table;
    width: 303px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin-left: 31px;
}
#skills>div:nth-child(2) span {
    font-family: myriad pro;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #0597BE;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="skills">
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>HTML</span>
        <span>CSS</span>
        <span>Javascript</span>        
    </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$('#skills>div:nth-child(1) div').eq(0).animate({
    height: 360
});

$('#skills>div:nth-child(1) div').eq(1).animate({
    height: 120
});

$('#skills>div:nth-child(1) div').eq(2).animate({
    height: 200
});
```

Can you think of a solution to my problem that achieves a bottom-to-top animation while at the same time spreads out all the relevant elements evenly on the x-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/aoxyLtLe/14/)

made some changes to your css

```
    #skills {
        position: absolute;
        width: 410px;
        height: 455px;
        top: 0px;
        left: 10px;   
    }


    #skills>div:nth-child(1) {
        float: left;
        height: 400px;
        display: table;
        width: auto;
        table-layout: fixed;
        margin-left: 31px;
        margin-top: 44px;
        width:100%;
    }

    #skills>div:nth-child(1) div {
        position: absolute;
        width: 77px;
        height: 0;
        background-color: #0597BE;
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        margin: 0px 12px;
        bottom:50px;
    }
    #skills>div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1){
        left:40px;
        }
    #skills>div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(2){
        left:138px;
        }
    #skills>div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(3){
        left:239px;
        }
    #skills>div:nth-child(2) {
        float: left;
        display: table;
        width: 303px;
        table-layout: fixed;
        margin-left: 31px;
    }
    #skills>div:nth-child(2) span {
        font-family: myriad pro;
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #0597BE;
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

**Edit**

check the updated fiddle

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/aoxyLtLe/18/)

rotating the div will fix it and made change to

```
#skills>div:nth-child(1) div{
    float:right /** from float left **/
}
```

Comment: Like I said in my original post, I don't want to set the left of each div manually using CSS as I will have too many divs, definitely more than three, possibly around 20. Please read the original posts carefully before answering in case your answer has already been rejected by the original post.

Comment: I thought about that as well but tried to avoid it :-P. Rotating it actually messes up the horizontal sequence of element (what used to be first is now last etc..) So it's actually best to use `transform: scaleY(-1);` instead. Thanks!